# GridLayout, split 2nd row into two equal parts

Tags: java, grid-layout

I am using the above layout. All i want is split the second row into two equal and half parts, where I can have a jlabel "enter:" on the left and a jtextfield on the right. How can I accomplish this? I use:

```
GridLayout gl = new GridLayout(2,1);
setLayout(gl);

JButton jb = new JButton("Click Me!");
jb.setFocusPainted(false);
add(jb);

JLabel jl = new JLabel("Enter:");
JTextField jt = new JTextField();
add(jl);
```

[image]

Comment: Is the picture expected result?

Comment: um, no as the 2nd row consists only of the jlabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to put another `JPanel` in the bottom row, which is configured to use `GridLayout`.

Code (tested):

```
this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

JButton button = new JButton("Click Me!");
JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));

JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter:");
JTextField textField = new JTextField();

bottomPanel.add(label);
bottomPanel.add(textField);

add(button);
add(bottomPanel);
```